# Dashing doesn't detect change of coffescript

Tags: javascript, ruby, coffeescript, dashing

I'm working on some [dashing](http://shopify.github.io/dashing/) widgets in a dashboard project.

Normally if I work on a coffeescript and I save it, I have to reload the page in the browser, and I can see the effect of my changes in the widget.

For some time the change won't do any effect in the browser. I thought, it may be a browser cache issue and I tried clear the cache, but nothing changed. I tried another browser, same issue.

I can see my changes in the browser only if I change the classname off the widget.

Is there any simpler method?

Comment: Can you restart the dashboard and see if it works?

Comment: Restart didn't help either.

Answer (score 2):

I encountered a similar issue. The widget would not refresh to reflect my html changes (new <h2> tag). Restarting / clear-cache were the first things I tried. I use Chrome and I found this note in the [Dashing-Workshop](https://github.com/Shopify/dashing/wiki/Dashing-Workshop) :

> Note: Chrome is sometimes weird, and it's possible that your browser isn't showing the number anymore in the widget. If that's the case load dashing in a brand new tab to clear the cache.

I resolved my issue by turning off caching "Developer Tools > Networking > Disable cache [x]"

Answer (score 0):

It shall work, Use chrome developer tool to debug it

- console.log to print to console
- use inspect element to see the html/css